# Correct usage of describeInstances amazon ec2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use the describeInstances function in amazon ec2 to get details about my instance 
using my tag id.  In the documentation it mentions use the filter,

> tag:key=value - The key/value combination of a tag assigned to the
>   resource, where tag:key is the tag's key.

I tried it in the following way:

```
var params1 = {
            Filters : [
                {
                    Tags      : [ {
                        Key   : key_name,
                        Value : key_value
                    } ]
                }
            ]
        };

ec2.describeInstances(params1, function(data, err) {
})
```

, but I get an error: Unexpected Token at Tags : 
What is the correct way to use this api?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The documentation is a little confusing, but you need to construct a filter name that includes the *tag:* prefix and your tag name. Here's a working example:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({
  region: 'eu-west-1'
});

var params = {
  Filters: [
    {
      Name: 'tag:Project',
      Values: ['foo']
    }
  ]
};

ec2.describeInstances(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) return console.error(err.message);

  console.log(data);
});
```

This returns all instances that have the tag *Project* set to the value *foo*.

Answer (score 0):

For those using version 3 of the JS AWS-SDK; there have been some changes since v2. You'd now use [DescribeInstancesCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/ec2/command/DescribeInstancesCommand/).

From that page:

```
import { EC2Client, DescribeInstancesCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ec2"; // ES Modules import
// const { EC2Client, DescribeInstancesCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-ec2"); // CommonJS import
const client = new EC2Client(config);
const input = { // DescribeInstancesRequest
  Filters: [ // FilterList
    { // Filter
      Name: "STRING_VALUE",
      //tag: - The key/value combination of a tag assigned to the resource. 
      //Use the tag key in the filter name and the tag value as the filter value. 
      //For example, to find all resources that have a tag with the key Owner and the value TeamA, specify tag:Owner for the filter name and TeamA for the filter value.
      Values: [ // ValueStringList
        "STRING_VALUE",
      ],
    },
  ],
  InstanceIds: [ // InstanceIdStringList
    "STRING_VALUE",
  ],
  DryRun: true || false,
  MaxResults: Number("int"),
  NextToken: "STRING_VALUE",
};
const command = new DescribeInstancesCommand(input);
const response = await client.send(command);
```

Here `config` can, for example, contain the `region` (see more at the bottom of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/ec2/).